# How to query subset of data from a file on azure datalake

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

My datalake has json files. Each file is a pandas dataframe represented as a json. So a file may have this inside:

```
[
   {
      "col1":"1",
      "col2":"3"
   },
   {
      "col1":"2",
      "col2":"4"
   }
]
```

Which translates into this dataframe:
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| 1    | 3    |
| 2    | 4    |

I work with datalake files using using `DataLakeServiceClient` from `azure.storage.filedatalake`.

What I want is to [query_file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakefileclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-filedatalake-datalakefileclient-query-file) to extract dataframe only partially before I read it.
**My question is what query text I must provide in order to achieve this? Is it possible to do it this way in the first place?**

Example below returns me the content of the whole file as a string. I read it into a pandas dataframe using `read_json`. I know that I can work with it as dataframe after I read it but I want to do my selection when querying.

Sample code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient, DelimitedJsonDialect
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

adls_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url='...', credential=ClientSecretCredential(...))
filesystem_client = adls_client.get_file_system_client('...')
file_client = filesystem_client.get_file_client('test_dataframe.json')

input_format = DelimitedJsonDialect(has_header=True)
reader = file_client.query_file(
    'SELECT * from DataLakeStorage', # the problem is here
    file_format=input_format
)
json_str = reader.readall().decode('utf8')
df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(json_str))
```

I tried using `SELECT col1 from DataLakeStorage` but it returns `{}\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selected_df = df['col1']` instead of `SELECT col1 from DataLakeStorage` to get only column1 from a JSON file. To get only the first row, you can use `selected_rows = df.query('col1 > 1')`.

Below is the complete code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient, DelimitedJsonDialect
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

client_id = "<clientId>"
client_secret = "<clientSecret>"
tenant_id = "<tenantId>"
account_name = "<storageAccountName>"
file_system_name = "<containerName>"
file_path = "<directory>/<filename>.json"
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    tenant_id=tenant_id
)
account_url = f'https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net'
adls_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credential)
filesystem_client = adls_client.get_file_system_client(file_system_name)
file_client = filesystem_client.get_file_client(file_path)
input_format = DelimitedJsonDialect(has_header=True)
reader = file_client.query_file('SELECT * from DataLakeStorage', file_format=input_format)
json_str = reader.readall().decode('utf8')
df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(json_str))

selected_df = df['col1']
selected_rows = df.query('col1 > 1')
print("First Row:")
print(selected_rows)
print("col1:")
print(selected_df)
```

You can get the output as below:

[image]